# Seeding Random number generator not working

Tags: c++, random

I have a c++ program that uses a random generator to create a cube. To create the cube I have this:

```
void generateSquare() {
  int num = 0;
  srand(time(NULL));

  for (int r = 0; r < MSQUARE; r++) {
    for (int c = 0; c < MSQUARE; c++) {
      do {
        num = (rand() % (MSQUARE * MSQUARE)) + 1;
      } while (!checkUnique(num));
      cube[r][c] = num;
    }
  }
}
```

It only allows a number to be generated one. This function is then wrapped in a do..while loop so that if the square doesn't meet a specific condition a new square will be generated until the one that does meet the condition is generated.

The problem is that it continually is generating the same square over and over again. I thought that the srand(time(NULL)) would seed the rand() function so that it would generate different random numbers each time to create a new unique square every time it is called but it looks like that is not happening.

```
void checkSquare() {
  do {
    generateSquare();
  } while (!perfect);
}
```

This is not the actual do...while loop but gives you an idea of how it's being called.

How do I make sure the seed is unique each time?

Answer (score 3):

You should call `srand` only once, at the beginning of your program. The reason why your seed is always the same is because `time` returns a number of seconds. Since you're calling it in a loop it always has the same value (until a second goes by).

Also if you can use C++11 or later you should look at the [pseudo-random number generation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random) in the standard library

Answer (score 0):

srand sets the seed of the rand function. If you set it to a specific number it will always return you the same sequence of numbers. You will use this if you want to test a program, otherwise you use rand() without srand().

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/srand/

Comment: From that link: "If seed is set to 1, the generator is reinitialized to its initial value and produces the same values as before any call to rand or srand." So unless you want it to produce the same values you need to call srand with a different value for each run of the program (hence the call to `time`).

Comment: The call to time is so that the seed value is different. The program can run for a minute and the seed value is not changing which is why I use time I thought that was the standard in using rand() you seed srand() with time because no two times would be the same and it's supposed to seed each time it needs to generate but the time isn't changing.